# Calculate the slope for every n days per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (sample):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['A', '2022-09-01', 2], ['A', '2022-09-02', 1], ['A', '2022-09-04', 3], ['A', '2022-09-06', 2],
        ['A', '2022-09-07', 1], ['A', '2022-09-07', 2], ['A', '2022-09-08', 4], ['A', '2022-09-09', 2],
        ['B', '2022-09-01', 2], ['B', '2022-09-03', 4], ['B', '2022-09-04', 2], ['B', '2022-09-05', 2],
        ['B', '2022-09-07', 1], ['B', '2022-09-08', 3], ['B', '2022-09-10', 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['group', 'date', 'value'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['diff_days'] = (df['date']-df['date'].groupby(df['group']).transform('first')).dt.days

   group       date  value  diff_days
0      A 2022-09-01      2          0
1      A 2022-09-02      1          1
2      A 2022-09-04      3          3
3      A 2022-09-06      2          5
4      A 2022-09-07      1          6
5      A 2022-09-07      2          6
6      A 2022-09-08      4          7
7      A 2022-09-09      2          8
8      B 2022-09-01      2          0
9      B 2022-09-03      4          2
10     B 2022-09-04      2          3
11     B 2022-09-05      2          4
12     B 2022-09-07      1          6
13     B 2022-09-08      3          7
14     B 2022-09-10      2          9
```

I would like to create a column called "slope" which shows the slope for every n (n = 3) days per group. This means that when the first date is "2022-09-01" and 3 days later are used for the calculation. The slope can be calculated using the "diff_days" (calculated by difference with the first value per group) and "value" columns. Here is the desired output:

```
data = [['A', '2022-09-01', 2, 0, 0.43], ['A', '2022-09-02', 1, 1, 0.43], ['A', '2022-09-04', 3, 3, 0.43], ['A', '2022-09-06', 2, 5, -0.5],
        ['A', '2022-09-07', 1, 6, -0.5], ['A', '2022-09-07', 2, 6, -0.5], ['A', '2022-09-08', 4, 7, -2], ['A', '2022-09-09', 2, 8, -2],
        ['B', '2022-09-01', 2, 0, 0.14], ['B', '2022-09-03', 4, 2, 0.14], ['B', '2022-09-04', 2, 3, 0.14], ['B', '2022-09-05', 2, 4, -0.5],
        ['B', '2022-09-07', 1, 6, -0.5], ['B', '2022-09-08', 3, 7, -0.5], ['B', '2022-09-10', 2, 9, -0.5]]
df_desired = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['group', 'date', 'value', 'diff_days', 'slope'])

   group        date  value  diff_days  slope
0      A  2022-09-01      2          0   0.43
1      A  2022-09-02      1          1   0.43
2      A  2022-09-04      3          3   0.43
3      A  2022-09-06      2          5  -0.50
4      A  2022-09-07      1          6  -0.50
5      A  2022-09-07      2          6  -0.50
6      A  2022-09-08      4          7  -2.00
7      A  2022-09-09      2          8  -2.00
8      B  2022-09-01      2          0   0.14
9      B  2022-09-03      4          2   0.14
10     B  2022-09-04      2          3   0.14
11     B  2022-09-05      2          4  -0.50
12     B  2022-09-07      1          6  -0.50
13     B  2022-09-08      3          7  -0.50
14     B  2022-09-10      2          9  -0.50
```

Here are some example calculations to give you an idea:

- For the first 3 days of group A: slope([0,1,3],[2,1,3])=0.43
- For the 3 days later of group A: slope([5,6,6],[2,1,2])=-0.5
- For again 3 days later of group A: slope([7,8],[4,2])=-2.0

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to determine the slope for every n days (this case 3 days) per group? Please note: Not all dates are included, so it is really every n days.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about the formula: `slope([0,1,3],[2,1,3])`?

Comment: Hi @ShubhamSharma, Yes of course. I wanted to show how the slope is calculated. So the x values are from "diff_days" and y values are from "value". It is the same as `linregress(x=[0,1,3],y=[2,1,3])`. Do you understand what I mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The results of my solution (below) do not agree with your expected output, @Quinten. I guess that the reason is that your last block appears to have 4 elements and not 3 or less as it is expected from your description of the problem.

Comment: Actually, your expected output is consistent with 2 last blocks of 2 elements, @Quinten!

Comment: My method got the same values as OP, I think what they have is correct. @PaulS

Comment: Thank you @PaulS, for being sharp. Although I like all the solutions below, I can only accept one. Thanks all!

Comment: @BeRT2me: the reason why you get the same results is the use of `np.array_split`, which does not split the series as wanted! For instance, `np.array_split(df['group'][df['group'].eq('B')], 3)` does the following split: `[[B, B, B], [B, B], [B, B]]`. However, the split wanted is: `[[B, B, B], [B, B, B], [B]]`!

Comment: Interesting, you are correct. I've fixed my answer. @PaulS

Comment: Now, our results agree, @BeRT2me! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Solution

```
df['n'] = df.groupby('group').cumcount() // 3
df.merge(
    df
    .groupby(['group', 'n'])
    .apply(lambda s: np.polyfit(s['diff_days'], s['value'], 1)[0])
    .reset_index(name='slope')
)
```

##### How this works?

- Create a sequential counter per group using `cumcount` then floor divide by `3` to get blocks of `3` rows
- Group the dataframe by  `group` column along with the blocks and aggregate with `np.polyfit` to get the slope
- `Merge` the aggregated frame back to original dataframe to broadcast the `slope` values

##### Result

```
   group       date  value  diff_days  n     slope
0      A 2022-09-01      2          0  0  0.428571
1      A 2022-09-02      1          1  0  0.428571
2      A 2022-09-04      3          3  0  0.428571
3      A 2022-09-06      2          5  1 -0.500000
4      A 2022-09-07      1          6  1 -0.500000
5      A 2022-09-07      2          6  1 -0.500000
6      A 2022-09-08      4          7  2 -2.000000
7      A 2022-09-09      2          8  2 -2.000000
8      B 2022-09-01      2          0  0  0.142857
9      B 2022-09-03      4          2  0  0.142857
10     B 2022-09-04      2          3  0  0.142857
11     B 2022-09-05      2          4  1  0.214286
12     B 2022-09-07      1          6  1  0.214286
13     B 2022-09-08      3          7  1  0.214286
14     B 2022-09-10      2          9  2  0.111111
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, using pandas `groupby`, `transform` and `apply`:

```
# size of the blocks
n = 3

# this is to form blocks of 3 elements for each group
df['blk'] = df.groupby('group')['date'].transform(
    lambda x: np.repeat(range(int(np.ceil(len(x)/n))), n)[range(len(x))])

# this function calculates the slopes for each block of 3 
def f(x):
    return x.assign(slope = np.polyfit(x['diff_days'], x['value'], 1)[0])

df.groupby(['group', 'blk'], group_keys=False).apply(f).drop('blk', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   group       date  value  diff_days     slope
0      A 2022-09-01      2          0  0.428571
1      A 2022-09-02      1          1  0.428571
2      A 2022-09-04      3          3  0.428571
3      A 2022-09-06      2          5 -0.500000
4      A 2022-09-07      1          6 -0.500000
5      A 2022-09-07      2          6 -0.500000
6      A 2022-09-08      4          7 -2.000000
7      A 2022-09-09      2          8 -2.000000
8      B 2022-09-01      2          0  0.142857
9      B 2022-09-03      4          2  0.142857
10     B 2022-09-04      2          3  0.142857
11     B 2022-09-05      2          4  0.214286
12     B 2022-09-07      1          6  0.214286
13     B 2022-09-08      3          7  0.214286
14     B 2022-09-10      2          9  0.111111
```

Answer (score 1):

so you need to:

1. split each group into groups of n elements (or less at end) - use Numpy array_split
2. calculate the slope - use Numpy polyfit
3. append n times (or less at end)

here goes:

```
n = 3
slopes = []
for k, g in df.groupby('group'):
    a = np.array_split(g['diff_days'].values, n)
    b = np.array_split(g['value'].values, n)
    for ab in zip(a,b):
        for x in ab[0]:
            slopes.append(np.polyfit(ab[0], ab[1], 1)[0].round(2))

df['slopes'] = slopes
```

Comment: I like your solution very much. However, I am not sure whether `np.array_split` is the right option, as I have just tested with `np.array_split(np.arange(5), 2)`, that outputs `[array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4])]` -- the first block has got more than `n=2` elements!

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df['diff_days'] = (df.groupby('group')['date']
                     .transform(lambda x: x-x.min()).dt.days)

n = 3
# Get the indices of every n values per group.
indices = chain.from_iterable(df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x[::n].index))

# Convert each group to a np.array.
arrays = df[['diff_days', 'value']].groupby(df.group).apply(np.array)

# Helper function; splits into groups of n size, and then does the polyfit.
func = lambda arr: [np.polyfit(*x.T, 1)[0]
                    for x in np.split(arr[:len(arr)-len(arr)%n], len(arr)//n)
                    +[arr[len(arr)-len(arr)%n:]]]

# Apply the function to each group,
# Then, at each index we calculated above, place the flattened results.
df.loc[indices, 'slope'] = list(chain.from_iterable(arrays.apply(func)))

# Front fill slope values.
df.slope = df.slope.ffill()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   group       date  value  diff_days     slope
0      A 2022-09-01      2          0  0.428571
1      A 2022-09-02      1          1  0.428571
2      A 2022-09-04      3          3  0.428571
3      A 2022-09-06      2          5 -0.500000
4      A 2022-09-07      1          6 -0.500000
5      A 2022-09-07      2          6 -0.500000
6      A 2022-09-08      4          7 -2.000000
7      A 2022-09-09      2          8 -2.000000
8      B 2022-09-01      2          0  0.142857
9      B 2022-09-03      4          2  0.142857
10     B 2022-09-04      2          3  0.142857
11     B 2022-09-05      2          4  0.214286
12     B 2022-09-07      1          6  0.214286
13     B 2022-09-08      3          7  0.214286
14     B 2022-09-10      2          9  0.111111
```